# Jekyll, show category for a single post

Tags: jekyll, categories, liquid

Using Jekyll - I want to display a list  of categories to which a given post belongs.

In my post.html layout, I have the following block of code which renders ALL of the site's categories.

```html
<p>Posted in: 
  {% for category in site.categories %}
    <a href="/blog/{{ category | first | slugize }}/">
      {{ category | first }}
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
</p>
```

What I would like to show instead is a list of the categories that this single post is in. I've tried replacing site.categories with page.categories & post.categories, to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `site.categories`, use `page.categories`. Also, you do not need the `first`-filter since you already loop over the array:

```
{% for category in page.categories %}
  <a href="/blog/{{ category | slugize }}/">
    {{ category }}
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```